# Trying to find word in string of a form value

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form and all my standard inputs are all PB for particleboard. however I would like to be able to search a string in a form value to report in a separate report as ply if it is plywood.

my example with obviously wrong syntax.

```
Private Sub UnfinishedInterior_AfterUpdate()

If [Forms]![Cover Sheet]![UnfinishedInterior].Value contains Ply in it Then

[Forms]![Cover Sheet]![CV8AppliedEnds].Value = DFirst
("CV8PlyName", "AppliedEndsPlyReport_Query") 

Else

If [Forms]![Cover Sheet]![UnfinishedInterior].Value contains PB in it Then 

[Forms]![Cover Sheet]![CV8AppliedEnds].Value = DFirst("CV8Name", "AppliedEndsReport_Query")

End Sub
```

The problem I seem to be having is finding the correct way of extracting the ply or PB string and applying my data from my table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [InStr Function](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/InStr-Function-85d3392c-3b1c-4232-bb18-77cd0cb8a55b) or a `Like` comparison to determine whether a string is contained in another string.

`InStr` returns the position of the second string within the first string when found, or zero when not found.

```vb
? InStr(1,"Hello World", "or")
 8 
? InStr(1,"abcdef", "xyz")
 0
```

The `Like` comparison returns True or False to indicate whether the string matches the pattern.

```vb
? "Hello World" Like "*or*"
True
? "abcdef" Like "*xyz*"
False
```

So for your `If` condition ...

```vb
If [Forms]![Cover Sheet]![UnfinishedInterior].Value contains Ply in it Then
```

... choose one of these ...

```vb
If InStr(1, [Forms]![Cover Sheet]![UnfinishedInterior].Value, "Ply") > 0 Then
If [Forms]![Cover Sheet]![UnfinishedInterior].Value Like "*Ply*" Then
```